# Better way to load EditorForModel/DisplayForModel than storing indicator in TempData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller which wants to load a view. The view's model should, sometimes, be in edit mode. As such, I've got the following code:

```
public ActionResult ExistingOrderDetails(int orderID, bool isEditMode)
{
    TempData["isEditMode"] = isEditMode;

    Order order = WorkflowManager.GetOrderByID(orderID);
    OrderDetailsModel orderDetailsModel = new OrderDetailsModel(order);
    return View("OrderDetails", orderDetailsModel);
}
```

in OrderDetails.ascx, I have the following:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CableSolve.Web.Models.Orders.OrderDetailsModel>" %>

<%
if((bool)TempData["isEditMode"])
{
    %><%=Html.EditorForModel()%><%
}
else
{
    %><%=Html.DisplayForModel()%><%
}
%>
```

This seems like a bit of a hack to me. Should I be splitting my OrderDetails.ascx into two seperate ViewModels, an EditableOrderDetails.ascx and a ReadOnlyOrderDetails.ascx? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to avoid `TempData` in this case.  I'd make two separate views and write in the action:

```
return View(isEditMode ? "OrderDetailsEdit" : "OrderDetailsDisplay", orderDetailsModel);
```